# Script to count files (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a script that goes through the archive location and counts up how many files there are.

This is what I have to far.

```
#!/bin/bash

archive_location="location/archive/"
count=0

for files in $archive_location/* $archive_location/.* 
do
   count=$($count+1)
done

echo "File count: " $count
```

When I run the file I get `line 8: 0+1: command not found` & `line 8: +1: command not found`

Please help me. This is my first time creating a bash script.

Comment: You meant `$(( $count + 1 ))`. You don't actually need the `$` in arithmetic context: `count=$(( count + 1 ))` would work, or both `(( count += 1 ))` and `(( ++count ))`. (Or `(( count++ ))`.)

Comment: You also should quote `$archive_location`, both times, in double quotes. It doesn't matter here, but in other contexts, you can get surprising behaviour due to word splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: @Benjamin W. after fixing the counter, I am getting `-bash: ./: Is a directory` when I run the script. I do not understand why I am getting this.

Comment: @Paincakes, running `bash -x yourscript` will log each command as it's invoked. That generally tends to make the cause of errors (like that one!) a fair bit more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just run `find` through `wc`

```
find /path/to/search -type f | wc -l
```

Edit:

Since you need to write a loop you need to correct your counter to one of the following:

```
count=$((count+1))
```

or

```
let count=$count+1
```

or for performance declare `count` as an integer and then you can simply use the `+=` operator:

```
declare -i count
count+=1
```

Comment: @HostFisson Yeah after googling around I found the same thing. However, my professor wants us to do via a loop.

Comment: @HostFisson Thanks for the help so far. After implementing `count=$((count+1))` I do not get my initial error. However, instead of getting `File count...` I get `-bash: ./: Is a directory`

Comment: This is caused by your for loop trying to loop over `$archive_location/.*`, instead of this turn on the dotglob setting `shopt -s dotglob` to include the hidden files.

Comment: @HostFisson I am assuming that I put that at the start of the script? Sorry for these noob question btw.

Comment: Correct, it is a setting that applies to the entire sesion, then your `*` globs will match files starting with `.`. At the moment the `.*` glob is matching the `.` and `..` directories which don't really exist, thus your error.

Comment: `let` is legacy syntax offered by bash but not mandated by the POSIX sh standard. Much better to use `$(( ))`, which all POSIX-compliant shells are guaranteed to support (whereas `declare -i` is basically pure bashism, not portable to anything else).

Comment: ...and with respect to the claim that `declare -i` improves runtime performance -- if you read `make_variable_value` in `variables.c`, you'll see that even in the `integer_p` case, the result of a retrieval is still assigned to a `char*`. There could well be some magic I'm missing, but my understanding of the code is that the flag in question is effectively setting constraints as opposed to improving runtime efficiency.

Comment: I figured out what was the problem it was that the `archive_location=$(path)` I forgot the `$` which was giving me the error.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The question is tagged 'Bash', so bashisim is completely appropriate here. Also regarding performance see https://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash where all the methods have been benchmarked and compared. Declaring at an integer does indeed improve performance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If you're going to ask that then why not ask why Bash even retain the `let` syntax. It is for completeness. The options were listed in no particular order, let the OP decide how he wants to proceed.

Comment: @HostFission, as for bashisms being appropriate in bash-tagged questions -- I agree with that *when they add value*. You've made a case for `declare -i` in that respect. On the other hand, showcasing (for example) `[ "$foo" == "$bar" ]` rather than `[ "$foo" = "$bar" ]` is just helping people pick up habits and finger memory that will follow them into scripts intended to be run with other shells. I'd argue that `let` is in the same category.

Comment: ...as for the claim re: "first", I was mistaken about ordering -- apologies, there. Was reading from a phone screen at the time, and evidently managed to confuse myself.